# Save rendered selection with computed CSS

Tags: css, web-scraping

Suppose I want to scrape part of a page to reproduce a particular rendering with, at most, a single CSS.

I can copy the full rendering [using browser console commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10144820/2662901), but that still produces HTML with classes referencing the CSS stack.  E.g.,

```
<h1 class="x">
    <span class="y">Here's a header</span>
</h1>
<div class="z">Here's some more text with a different format</div>
```

Is there a way to either:

1. Get all styles expanded inline?
2. Get all referenced styles defined in a single "computed" CSS block?